# Can you explain the output of the following Swift Projected Value?

Tags: swift5

```
@propertyWrapper
struct smallNumber {
    private var num: Int
    private var maximum: Int
    var projectedValue: Bool
    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get { return num }
        set {
            if num > maximum {
                num = maximum
                projectedValue = true
            }

            else {
                num = newValue
                projectedValue = false
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        num = 0
        maximum = 12
        projectedValue = false
    }

    init(wrappedValue: Int) {
        maximum = 12
        projectedValue = false
        num = min(wrappedValue, maximum)
    }

    init(wrappedValue: Int, maximum: Int) {
        self.maximum = maximum
        projectedValue = false
        num = max(wrappedValue, maximum)
    }
}

struct Rectangle {
    @smallNumber var height: Int
    @smallNumber var width: Int

    var area: Int {
        get {
            return height * width
        }
    }
}

var x = Rectangle()
x.height = 9
x.width = 89
//x.width = 78
print(x.$height, x.$width, x.area)
```

Hi, I am learning swift and I am having trouble in the above code. In the [swift reference(Projected Values)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html), it's written that if we set the value of x greater than 12 then projectedValue becomes true. But after running the above code x.$width prints false. After removing the comment at 2nd last line x.$width prints true. Can someone explain me how is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copied the code incorrectly.

You have

```swift
if num > maximum {
```

but need

```swift
if newValue > maximum {
```